# Browser.close() with a loop to open a new window

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm looking for help to run a loop with **selenium**. I want to open a main page, then open a window when clicking on a link, then swith to the new window, and close the new window to switch back to the main page. my goal is to do this operations many times, but when I run the code, it works one time (*for k=0*) and then I have the following message of error:

```
  File "/Users/al/Desktop/code.py", line 34, in <module>
  window_after = browser.window_handles[x+1]

  IndexError: list index out of range
```

If anyone know how to execute the full code, it would be great!! 
Thank you.

Here is the code that I'm trying to run:

```
import time
import re
import traceback
import sys
import csv
import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
from random import randint
from lxml import etree
from lxml.cssselect import CSSSelector
import bs4 as bs
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
browser.get('https://www.vivino.com/explore?e=eJwdizsKgDAUBG-zdRQst9QDBKzEIj5jCPhUovi5vdFqYGdHEwtoXGig7mZlDORhYyGsW4st2zDxdCn6w81QIdaBW4risXL0u-A6uj7ffpS53jOnhPCt5gXGoR73')
list1=browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*/div[@class="explorerCard__explorerCard--3Q7_0 explorerPageResults__explorerCard--3q6Qe"]/div[2]/div/a/span[2]')
for k in list1:
    time.sleep(2.5)
    k.click()
    time.sleep(2)
    x=list1.index(k)
    print(x)
    window_after = browser.window_handles[x+1]
    browser.switch_to_window(window_after)
    browser.close()
    browser.switch_to_window(browser.window_handles[0])
```

Comment: There is no item on index 'x+1' in list window_handles. Debug content of windows_handles, did you start counting from 0?

Answer (score 0):

```
window_after = browser.window_handles[1]
```

instead of

```
window_after = browser.window_handles[x+1]
```

Because, `browser.close()` will close the last tab, so, the `browser.window_handles` 's length can be 2 or 1.

Answer (score 0):

Its easier to collect all the window handles and switch to the new one to perform actions on it. see the solution below,

```
window_current = browser.current_window_handle
print(window_current)

for k in list1:
    time.sleep(2.5)
    k.click()
    time.sleep(2)
    x=list1.index(k)
    print(x)
    handles = browser.window_handles
    print(len(handles))
    for handle in handles:
        if handle != window_current:
            browser.switch_to.window(handle) 

    print(browser.current_window_handle)
    browser.close()
    browser.switch_to.window(window_current)
```

Answer (score 0):

> IndexError: list index out of range

The above error appear because you want try switch to tab index based on  `[x+1]`, it will looks like this :

```
browser.window_handles[1]
browser.window_handles[2]
browser.window_handles[3]
etc...
```

Whereas you will only have 2 maximum windows.

After click each `k` element you just need switch to second tab with `.window_handles[1]`, and initialize the origin window before your loop, it will look simpler:

```
origin_win = browser.current_window_handle
for k in list1:
    k.click()
    time.sleep(2)
    browser.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[1])
    browser.close()
    browser.switch_to.window(origin_win)
```